# PySpark converting timestamps less than 2148 to null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following code produces the correct output:

```
import datetime, pytz
sc.parallelize([[datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(2148)]]).toDF().take(1)[0][0]

output: datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 35, 48)
```

Reducing the timestamp below 2148 results in null/None:

```
sc.parallelize([[datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(2147)]]).toDF().take(1)[0][0]

output: None
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pyspark bug that will be resolved in 2.1.1 and 2.2.0 releases. For details see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19561